# Roblox, custom chat filter

Tags: lua, roblox

So, I would like to add my own chat filter to my game, how would I do this?

eg:
Player says: "DIE"
Goes through chat filter and comes out as: "###" or any other string I specify.

Comment: How have you set up your chat so far?

Comment: I haven't done anything so far, I don't know where ro start.

Comment: You should start by [creating a Roblox game](https://developer.roblox.com/articles/Creating-Your-First-Game). You'll need to learn enough Lua scripting to modify the [Lua Chat System](https://developer.roblox.com/articles/Lua-Chat-System). You'll be looking to add a Filter Function that replaces words in each message's content using [`string.gsub`](https://developer.roblox.com/articles/Lua-Libraries/string). Maybe this helps you get started? I would recommend for you to ask questions about the specific thing you're stuck at *right now*, so answers can get straight to the point.

Comment: @Anko that looks like it could make a pretty good answer, with just a little more detail about how to set up this filter function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some games have their own custom chat guis. You could create one, then have an event that would fire in the server when a player sends a message. Creating the gui is beyond the scope of this question, but the event could have some pseudocode like this:

```
if(string.match(message, "DIE")) then
    addMessageToGui("###")
else
    addMessageToGui(message)
end
```

For more resources on remote events, you can learn how to communicate between the client and server here:

https://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=Remote_Functions_%26_Events